# Want to create an bash alias which accepts function with argument

Tags: linux, bash, alias, zsh

I want to create alias which would do something like that

```
ssh -i {location of file} username@host

sf() {
    ssh -i ~/.ssh/key user2@$1
}

alias ssf=sf
```

and i have to

```
ssf host
```

If i do in this way, my autocomplete (zsh, iterm) will not work. Was thinking of calling a function in alias which accepts arguments. Any help?

Comment: I suggest to us a function.

Comment: the autocomplete is not working then. I guess it sees first word as ssh then list all the hosts.

Comment: @shaileshgupta: So what is your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

A quick and simple method to creating an alias that accepts arguments would be something similar to this pseudo-code:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -r -a n=('$1' '$2' '$3' '$4' '$5')

function main() {

    command -i ${n[0]} -f ${n[1]} --another-arg ${n[2]}
}

main
```

If I want this script available to all users, I will usually `sudo su` to login as root, then I will make the file executable and save the script file to `/usr/bin/` directory. This will allow you to use the name of the script as a terminal command. While root, apply the proper permissions to the script, `chown root script.sh` if you want only root user to have access. If you want a custom command name to call the script, name the script the alias you wish to use.

## Explaining the pseudo-code

The `declare -r -a` is the syntax to create a read-only array. `n=` is the array variable which will hold the values for each argument you use with the tool. `('$1''$2''$3''$4''$5')` are the argument variables up to `5` arguments. `$1` will be the first argument, `$2` will be the next, and onto the last. Each of these argument variable will hold the value you enter on the command line when using your script alias.

Next we have the `main()` function which will house the commands you wish to run. Inside this `main()` function you can see braces with the `n` variable with brackets holding a number such as `${n[0]}`. What this is, is calling the value of your `n` array. Array values in bash are called with numbers starting with `0` rather than starting with `1`. So `0` is the first value, or `$1`, and `1` is the second value, or `$2`, and so on.

## .bashrc method

Another method for creating the alias in the same way is editing your `.bashrc` file for the user you are logged in under. So according to the user you would:

Enter cd command and hit enter to change to your home directory where .bashrc is located for the current user.

```
cd
```

Then using nano, open .bashrc.

```
nano .bashrc
```

Scroll to the bottom of the file and add the following:

```
alias your_alias="bash path/to/your/bash/script.sh'
```

Once the alias is set, type in `ctrl+x` to save the file. Nano will prompt you to confirm. Just type in `y` to confirm the save. Next you can reload `.bashrc` so you can use the command right away or you can reboot so it is available upon next boot. To reload `.bashrc` you will do the following:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

And thats it! Your alias is ready. Now just use the alias as a normal CLI tool command, add your arguments as you need them, and hit enter and your script should work just fine.

## Disclaimer

These methods may not be the most effective or the most secured for using your own aliases. However they should be sufficient to get you started. If anyone wishes to add to, or edit this answer to make it more informative and accurate (if it is inaccurate) feel free to do so. Hope this helps.